# How to keep on changing time In C# web application

Tags: asp.net

I want to show time taken my function/process in C#.When I click on button show,I want show time in label as 0,and keep on changing like1,2,3,4,5.In button click event writing/processing/executing query ,when that process over I want stop time.How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use **Stopwatch**. It can even measure as low as CPU-ticks.

Example: http://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch